# How to specify an execution strategy when calling Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(…)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using stored procedures in my code and using 
`Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters);`

Like so:

```
IEnumerable result = database.SqlQuery<MyThing>("StoredProcedureName @ParameterName", storedProcedureParameter).AsQueryable();
```

to get the results as a collection of required type. Sometimes, when network is particularly loaded, I can get a situation when an exception gets thrown that says

> “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing…”

I have solved this issue before in EF by creating an execution strategy and applying it to EF configuration.

Now from the stack trace I discover that this also uses an execution strategy, but this time it is the [default DbExecutionStrategy](https://github.com/mrward/entityframework-sharpdevelop/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DbExecutionStrategy.cs). I tried to make extension methods for the default execution strategy, but ultimately, could not make that work, because my execution strategy relies on new fields and all that jazz. I also have `codeConfigurationType="MyNameSpace.CustomConfiguration"` in `<entityFramework>` tag in app.config.

How can I make sure that `Database.SqlQuery()` uses my execution strategy?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where my DbExecutionStrategy was being completely ignored. I was able to force it to be used by following the guide here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn307226(v=vs.113).aspx under the section **Manually Call Execution Strategy**.

You basically want to:

```
var executionStrategy = new MyExecutionStrategy(); //manually instantiate your execution strategy

executionStrategy.Execute( //pass whatever you need to do as an action to the Execute method of your execution strategy
    () => 
    { 
        using (var context = new Entities()) 
        { 
            //...do stuff
            context.SaveChanges();
        } 
    });
```

The part about the SuspendExecutionStrategy property should only be necessary if you want to be able to turn the execution strategy off (in case you're working with transactions).